# Can't see Allocated Memory in DDMS view in Eclipse

Tags: android, ubuntu

I'm trying to follow the Memory analysis article from the Android Blog http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html, but while using the DDMS perspective in Eclipse when I select the process I want to watch on the Devices view, and then when I want to check the Allocated memory under the Heap tab I cannot see anything because the table in which this info is shown is too small and there is no way to resize it .

I've attached a screenshot because I realize it can be difficult to describe.

(The table I'm referring to is the one with headers ID, Heap Size, Allocated, Free %Used and #Objects ) The headers are shown

I'm using Eclipse Helios on Ubuntu 11.10

[image]

Comment: This appears to be a bug -- I have filed [an issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20869) on it.

Comment: and what do you know it seems to be still present in the latest SDK (14)